# magento login using SOAPpy in python

Tags: python, magento, soap

Hello i am new to magento. i have a issue about login using `SOAPProxy` 
My code look like

```
from SOAPpy import *
server = SOAPProxy('http://localhost/magento/api/soap/?wsdl')
session = server.login('admin','my_password')
```

but it gives me a syntax error like

```
xml.sax._exceptions.SAXParseException: <unknown>:1:0: syntax error
```

I am sure that my userid and password are correct.

Comment: put your `'http://localhost/magento/api/soap/?wsdl'` here

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry i exactly don't know where the wsdl is located. i am using ubuntu and magento installation path is ~/var/www/.
do me a favour, can you please tell me default path of wsdl.

Comment: try your default gateway example 192.168.1.1

Comment: Do you need to use SOAPpy? XML-RPC is nicer.

Comment: @utility i have used xml-rpc too but at that time it give me the error of 
`xmlrpclib.ProtocolError: <ProtocolError for localhost/magento/index.php/api/xmlrpc: 302 Found>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the URL to the WSDL could be wrong:

1. The wsdl parameter should be set to something that evaluates to `!== null`, i.e. `?wsdl=1` (look into `app/code/core/Mage/Api/Server/.../Adapter/Soap.php`, replace '...' with one of 'Wsi', 'V2', or '')
2. You might have url rewrites disabled so try adding `index.php` to your url. In your example, this would be `http://localhost/magento/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl=1`
3. Finally, I don't know much about Python ot the SOAPpy library, but it might be incompatible with the Soap Api v1. Try using v2 or wsi and see if there is any change.